# TS2604: JSX element type 'Header' does not have any construct or call signature

Tags: reactjs, typescript, semantic-ui-react

I am using semantic-ui-react in my react app with typescript and it is giving error. The project uses PnPify.

> TS2604: JSX element type 'Header' does not have any construct or call
>   signatures.

I am very new to typescript and don't know how to resolve this, here is a component

```
import React from 'react'
import Card from '../UI/Card'
import {Header } from 'semantic-ui-react'


const Test: React.FC = () => {

    return (
         <div>
             <Card>
                <Header> Test </Header>
            </Card>
        </div>
    )
}


export default Test
```

[image]

EDIT: I copy-pasted this definition file for types and it seems to be working but I am not sure this is the right way to do it
https://gist.github.com/tomitrescak/6261ad27dbe43aad03b2497721d751f5

Comment: Can you mouse-over (or whatever is the gesture your IDE provides) `Header` and tell its exact type?

Comment: @zerkms I have added an image in the question

Comment: What version of `semantic-ui-react` do you have?

Comment: @zerkms 0.88.2 , the latest one

Comment: Right, then the problem is in the `Card` declaration, can you show it.

Comment: @zerkms no it isn't even if I remove the card it still gives the error.

Comment: So you say that even `<div><Header>foo</Header></div>` code wouldn't render? What version of typescript you run?

Comment: @zerkms 3.8.3-pnpify

Comment: So you say that even `<div><Header>foo</Header></div>` code wouldn't render?

Comment: @zerkms yes it won't :(

Comment: It's really really really weird then.

Comment: Same issue in May 2022.

Comment: @SUMITNIHALANI May i know where u replace  types file ? I am still getting this error.

Comment: I have the same error as well, December 2022

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this error by checking the versions of my @types/react and @types/react-dom package.

In my case I had React version 16.X.X installed, but version 18.X.X of the @types packages.

When I changed the @types packages to 16.X.X to match my react version, the error went away.

Answer (score 0):

You can also get this error when you end up installing the package to the wrong directory.

Make sure your app directory (where you ran create-react-app and installed all dependencies) is where you install semantic-ui-react as well.